# Is it possible to do a Select statement within a Case statement

Tags: sql, teradata

Is something like this possible?

```
SELECT WH_ACC_NO,
    CASE
        WHEN FIELD2 IN (SELECT * FROM TABLEB)
            THEN 'PASS'
        ELSE 'FAIL'
     END
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Wouldn't a quick test be faster than asking a SO question? BTW. That's a case _expression_.

Comment: BTW2, tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: @jarlh depends on the the teachers you had, the books you read and how old you are: tables can have records and fields or rows and columns.

Comment: @forpas, I only trust ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), i.e. the SQL standard specification. No records or fields there...

Comment: @jarlh **2016**!!!! If you started in 1989 learning dBase, your terminilogy would not be so strict...

Comment: @forpas, what a coincident - I started learning SQL in 1989! (My first database class, but not with dBase.)

Comment: @jarlh so what was at that time the terminology? Records and fields where everywhere. We only used rows and columns in Lotus 123.

Comment: @forpas, we were teached tables, rows and columns. And the SQL-1 standard from 1989 says the same.

Comment: @jarlh this is why *it depends on the the teachers you had, the books you read and how old you are*

Comment: @Klippy . . . You code should be fine if `tableB` has only one column.  Normally, though, you would specify the column explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

`FIELD2` should be mapped with `TABLEB` then you can do :

```
SELECT ta.WH_ACC_NO,
       (CASE WHEN tb.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL
             THEN 'PASS'
             ELSE 'FAIL'
        END)
FROM TABLEA ta LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLEB tb
     ON tb.FIELD2 = ta.FIELD2;
```

I have used `FIELD2` with `TABLEB`, you can correct the `ON` clause with correct column name.

Comment: Might return duplicate rows when `TABLEB.FIELD2` is not unique

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a SELECT within CASE is a bit limited in Teradata, you need to write a *Correlated Scalar Subquery* to avoid the *3771 Illegal expression in WHEN clause of CASE expression* error:

```
SELECT WH_ACC_NO,
    CASE -- when FieldWhatever is not unique this shuld be MAX(FieldWhatever)
        WHEN FIELD2 = (SELECT FieldWhatever FROM TABLEB AS b WHERE a.Field2 = b.FieldWhatever)
            THEN 'PASS'
        ELSE 'FAIL'
     END
FROM TABLEA AS a
```

Answer (score 0):

This does work normally. Code in the example below.

```
declare @t1 table (num int)
insert into @t1 select 1
insert into @t1 select 2

declare @t2 table (value nvarchar(10), broj int)
insert into @t2 select 'test1', 1
insert into @t2 select 'test2', 3
```

select case when broj in (select num from @t1) then 'good' else 'bad' end
from @t2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

I tested this using the following:

```
select top 50 ID, Name, DOB
into #Population 
from Table1


select CASE 
            when ID in (select ID from #Population) 
                then 1 
            else 0 
        end as Number 
 from #Population
```

I am sure there are limitations but this should answer your question.

Good Luck!

Comment: When I try this it comes up as "Illegal expression in WHEN clause"

Comment: @klippy I just tested this query again and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It's a Teradata limitation, must be rewritten using a *Correlated Scalar Subquery*

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should know that you can't type the * in the inner query because it will return more than one result.so here is the solution.

```
SELECT ta.WH_ACC_NO,
       (CASE WHEN tb.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL
             THEN 'PASS'
             ELSE 'FAIL'
        END)
FROM TABLEA ta JOIN
     TABLEB tb
     ON tb.FIELD2 = ta.FIELD2;
```

Comment: Of course you can type `*` if it's a single column table. And you must use a LEFT JOIN, otherwise you'll never get NULLs in `tb.FIELD2`