# how to use case when to create a new column in table B to show if data from table A also in table B

Tags: case, teradata, teradatasql

When I try following code it returns attached error code

```
select  acct_key,
       (case when acct_key in (
                                select acct_key
                                from table_A
                              ) 
       then 1 else 0 end) as acct_indicator
from  table_B;
```

Executed as Single statement.  Failed [804 : 08S01] Socket communication failure for Packet transmit Wed May 25 12:01:18 CDT 2022 socket orig=VTDSSBP.rw.discoverfinancial.com local=/10.2.181.125:61593 remote=VTDSSBPcop2.rw.discoverfinancial.com/170.217.201.43:1025 keepalive=false nodelay=false receive=65536 send=64512 linger=10 traffic=0 concurrent=3 contimeout=10000 conwait=1000 connecttime=38 connecttotaltime=38 connectattempts=1 connectfailures=0 reconnectattempts=0 recoverable=false redrive=false failurecache={} cid=1221d607 sess=106395528 java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)   at ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416298/2527905

Answer (score 0):

attempt 1:

```
select  a.acct_key,
       case when exists (
                            select acct_key
                            from table b
                            where a.acct_key = b.acct_key
                        ) 
       then 1 
       else 0
       end as acct_indicator
from  table a;
```

failed as
it returns Illegal expression in When Clause of case expression

attempt 2:

```
select a.acct_key,
       case when b.acct_key is not null
       then 'yes'
       else 'no'
       end as acct_ind
from table a
left join table b 
on a.acct_key = b.acct_key;
```

succeed

Comment: Scalar Correlated Subqueries are hard to optimize, query #2 should be preferred, it probably shows a better plan/execution.